# How do I prevent broadcast messages to console for specific application?

Tags: command-line, server, syslog, rsyslog, nut

I am running NUT UPS Tools server on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS system.  I have to resart the NUT driver every 15 minutes, and each time it restarts the **upsmon** application broadcasts a message to the console:

> Broadcast message from root@ContaCam01-Ubuntu (somewhere) (Mon Dec 20
> 22:30:10
> Communications with UPS cyberpower-j@localhost established

This is what is in the log:

> Dec 20 22:30:10 ContaCam01-Ubuntu upsmon[927]: Communications with UPS
> cyberpower-j@localhost established

I have looked into this, and found that **sudo dmesg -n 1** is supposed to stop these messages.  But it doesn't.

Is there a way, using syslog.conf or rsyslog.conf to prevent this particular message from **upsmon** from being broadcast to the console?

Comment: In you upsmon.conf you can set `NOTIFYFLAG` for upsmon `NOTIFY` events, remove `WALL` for events you don't wish to broadcast.

Comment: Removing the WALL in NOTIFYFLAG for upsmon does not stop these broadcasts.

Comment: upsmon broadcasts to the terminal (console) these messages to all users each time I restart driver: /sbin/upsdrvctl start.  Removing WALL from NOTIFYFLAG events does not stop these broadcasts.  Nor does executing sudo dmesg -n 1.  My question is simple:  what other ways are there to stop upsmon from broadcasting these messages to all users when NUT driver is restarted.